# Open Modelica where to put lib folder

Tags: openmodelica

I accidently moved the lib folder for Open Modelica, and now, it's not where it should suppose to be. Can anyone please tell me, where specifically shout this folder be so the model will operate normally. Thanks

Moved the folder around other folders, but the program won't function normally.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the `lib` folder as shown in the below figure,
[image: Installation location]

In case of Windows, for me it is in `C:\Program Files\OpenModelica1.19.2-64bit`, so if you have installed with default option you can find them somewhere here. If the `lib` folder is misplaced then modelica libraries won't get loaded because `MODELICAPATH` by default is looking to `C:\Program Files\OpenModelica1.19.2-64bit\lib\omlibrary`.P.S: The path locations are specific to my computer path, just pasted them here for better understanding.